# Error in role redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, role

I am trying to make an access role in my system. I have these two roles ; Admin and user. In my login page, I put this line of code:

```
        if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Administrator"))
            Response.Redirect("~/4_Admin/Page1.aspx");
        else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(Login1.UserName, "Users"))
            Response.Redirect("~/3_User/Expense.aspx");
```

When user role logged in, they are directed to the correct page but for the admin, it gives me this error,

**The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /Self_studies/login.aspx**

```
 <membership>
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="Connection" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" applicationName="SampleApplication"/>
    </providers>
  </membership>
  <profile>
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="Connection" applicationName="SampleApplication"/>
    </providers>
  </profile>
  <roleManager enabled="true">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add connectionStringName="Connection" applicationName="SampleApplication"
        name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
  </roleManager>
    <compilation debug="false">

      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>

    </compilation>
    <!--
        The <authentication> section enables configuration 
        of the security authentication mode used by 
        ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
    -->
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
```

I think I have checked the name and went through all the coding for so many times. Is there anything that I can do to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have all the Pages that you reference here?

Comment: Yeap. I do. Double checked it. But still same error

Comment: Have you tried stepping though your code to see what page it is redirecting to or monitoring the network traffic in the browser with one of the browser dev tools?

Comment: Are you running the site from IIS or Visual studio development server? Also are you trying to debug or accessing the URL directly from browser?

Comment: Im running from vsd and debug it from the syst.

Comment: I think something wrong with my admin role. Because, when i changed with some other page, it gimme that error too. I dont know why. I also set the manage access rules in the web tools. Still cannot.

Comment: Are you using Forms authentication or Windows authentication?

Comment: You are using RoleManager right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx Also your roles Administrator and Users have the same case?

Comment: Im using forms authentication.@M.Babcock

Comment: Please post the web.config and the role names in the database in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Reference this- [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417083524/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121405-1.aspx)
try to configure your role manager as:

```
<roleManager enabled="true"
                 defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider">
      <providers>
         <add name="CustomizedRoleProvider"
              type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
              connectionStringName="MyDB"
              applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

and at login button check user role as: Ref: [Validation on current user](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/63bfa23f-b1d3-4150-8711-b523de91ad1c)

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
        Response.Redirect("~/PageA.aspx");
    else
        Response.Redirect("~/PageB.aspx");
```

Comment: still cannot. the resource cannot be found. I dont understand why it cant be found.

Comment: have you run the admin website to configure membership database???.. check the <autherizttion> section..